# why no letter "ס" samech in viduy of yom Kippur?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, viduy-confession

The viduy of the על חטא lists sins from alef to taf, yet the letter samech ס is switched to a sin ש. 
Why?

(Interestingly I noticed that in between sections of viduy we say סלח לנו מחל לנו כפר לנו, which is roshei teivos סמך. So the samech is there, but hidden.)

Comment: Many times ס and ש are interchanged. I feel like this question applied in more contexts. Most of the piyutim and selichos I've seen that are Alef beis use ש instead. It might just be practically more words start with ש than ס

Comment: ברנו ממצוותיך ולא שוה לנו

Answer (score 2):

Many acrostic piyutim interchange ס with שׂ because of their sound being the same. I suppose it is because the author could not find a fitting word that began with ס. One example of this would be in the prayer "[L'chai Olamim](http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=63&recordings=1)", in which the line for ס goes:

> .הַסִּגּוּי וְהַשֶּֽׂגֶב  לְחַי עוֹלָמִים

Also in the prayer "[Kel Adon](http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=67)" on Shabbat, the line for ס is replaced with a שׂ:

> .שְׂמֵחִים בְּצֵאתָם וְשָׂשִׂים בְּבוֹאָם

These are just two examples, but it seems that it is quite common in acrostic prayers. So Vidui is not the only prayer which replaces ס with a שׂ in the acrostic.

Comment: However, there's none that changes ט with ת or כ with ק or א with ע. A similar sound is not **a reason** to change.

Comment: @AlBerko Maybe not, but that's what they do. Let me ask you this - would you switch beit and veit? Shin and sin seem more like a difference between beit and veit and less like separate letters.

Comment: ב is a letter and it can take two forms, just as H2 (hydrogen) can have 2 forms gas and liquid. But H2 cannot change to C or N, just as ט cant change to ת or ס to ש.